# jQuery Mobile: Full width of <select>s fieldgroup

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a date picker laid out **horizontally**:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Your Birth Date:</legend>
    <select name="cboDay" id="cboDay"></select>
    <select name="cboMonth" id="cboMonth"></select>
    <select name="cboYear" id="cboYear"></select>
</fieldset>
```

How can I force it to **render full width**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the navbar would be an option?

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/DjsWv/

Code:

```
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><select name="cboDay" id="cboDay" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false"><option>Day</option><option value="1">1</option></select></li>
        <li><select name="cboMonth" id="cboMonth" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false"><option>Month</option><option value="1">1</option></select></li>
        <li><select name="cboYear" id="cboYear" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false"><option>Year</option><option value="1">1</option></select></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```