# horizontal select full width jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Im attempting to ask a user for their birth day and im running into a few stylistic problems.

You should be able to understand my problem from this http://jsfiddle.net/DjsWv/14/

I started with:

```
         <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <legend>Date of Birth:</legend>
            <select name="select-choice-month" id="select-choice-month" data-icon="false">
                <option >Month</option>
                <option value="jan">Jan</option>
            </select>
            <select name="select-choice-day" id="select-choice-day" data-icon="false">
                <option >Day</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
            </select>
            <select name="select-choice-year" id="select-choice-year">
                <option >Year</option>
                <option value="2011">2012</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
```

problem here is i dont like that the width is not full or 100%

The only solution I have seen is using the navbar which does not look appeasing to me... any ideas on how to get this horizontal control group to display as the full/standard width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PUVkw/

#### HTML

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="custom-fieldset">
    <legend>Date of Birth:</legend>

    <select name="select-choice-month" id="select-choice-month" data-icon="false">
        <option >Month</option>
        <option value="jan">Jan</option>
    </select>

    <select name="select-choice-day" id="select-choice-day" data-icon="false">
        <option >Day</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>

    <select name="select-choice-year" id="select-choice-year">
        <option >Year</option>
        <option value="2011">2012</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

#### CSS

```
.custom-fieldset .ui-controlgroup-controls {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.custom-fieldset .ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-select {
    width: 33.33% !important;
}
```

Don't forget to add a custom class name to your fieldset, in my case it is called: **`custom-fieldset`**

### Edit

Following **[ericjbasti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1922609/ericjbasti)** comment here's a solution with custom id and without **`!important`**: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/PUVkw/1/

Comment: This answer is correct, but my only recommendation would be to give the fieldset an ID so you don't have to use !important

Answer (score 2):

Its not necessary to overwrite any style. You can use the navbar behavior even in a form.

See: [jQuery Mobile: Full width of <select>s fieldgroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040993/jquery-mobile-full-width-of-selects-fieldgroup)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't keen on using the navbar solution above, so looked for a cleaner CSS override. No !importants in sight and if you don't wrap them in the full-width element they don't interfere with the jQuery Mobile theme.

HTML

```
<div class="full-width">
   <div class="ui-field-contain country-select">
      <label for="countrySelect" class="ui-screen-hidden">Select Country</label>
         <select id="countrySelect" data-native-menu="false">
            <option class="default-option">Select Country</option>
         </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.full-width .ui-field-contain .ui-select {
   width: 100%;
}
```