# Apps Script Web App elements are too small when viewed on a phone

Tags: mobile, google-apps-script, jquery-mobile, web-applications

On my phone, my select buttons end up being very small.  I'm trying to get them to take up, combined, 100% of the horizontal space, so that each one will take up 33% of the horizontal space.

On my computer, they take up 100% of horizontal space, like I want.

How do I fix this for my mobile?

[image: Edited screenshot from phone]

html:

```
<div data-role="page" id="Gauntlet">
  <div data-role="header">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div data-role="collapsible-set">
      <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-mini="true">
        <h3>Gauntlet Traits:</h3>
        <div class="ui-field-contain">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="custom-fieldset">
            <select id="myList1" data-mini="true"></select>
            <select id="myList2" data-mini="true"></select>
            <select id="myList3" data-mini="true"></select> 
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="submit" data-mini="true">Submit</button> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="table_div"></div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer">
    <h2></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.custom-fieldset .ui-controlgroup-controls {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.custom-fieldset .ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-select {
    width: 33.33% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As written in [view-port meta tag documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#addMetaTag(String,String)),

> Meta tags included directly in an Apps Script HTML file are ignored. Only the following meta tags are allowed.

So, add the meta tag server side:

```
return HtmlService
        .createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
```

Comment: Well, I tried that... but that causes some parts of my code to completely stop working, such as the fact that I load data to those form elements at run time, and the submit button below them also stopped working.  

I was using .createTemplateFromFile and .evaluate... which, of course, don't have the .addMetaTag method.

Comment: @Tulsa After `.evaluate()`, you get `HtmlOutput`, which does have a `.addMetaTag()` method. The other issues seem unrelated to the issue at hand

Comment: I do not follow that at all... currently, I just return the .createTemplate call.

Comment: return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();

Comment: @Tulsa `return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate().addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');`

Comment: oooh, right.... gotcha.  I was attempting to do the .addMetaTag before the evaluate, I see.

Comment: yess, that works, and it looks soooo much better than the navbar version.  Thanks!

Comment: I have zero experience with `google-apps-script`.  Just for the sake of curiosity, if you can add a `head` section to your index file, could you please explain why `addMetaTag` works better than adding the meta tag directly inside the `head` of that index file?

Comment: @deblocker Thanks to Google which restricts the html served and documents it in nooks and crevices of the documentation. That's why I linked the doc. Read my link to documentation in the answer. It explicitly states the reason: "All meta tags directly put in the file are ignored and only the following meta tags are allowed."

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Mobile Grids as described here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/grids-buttons/

```js
$(document).on("collapsiblecreate", function(e) {
  /* Add a nice smooth animation to the collapsible */
  $(this)
    .on("collapsiblebeforeexpand", function(event) {
      $(this).find(".ui-collapsible-content").each(function() {
        $(this).stop().slideDown("fast");
      });
      return true;
    })
    .on("collapsiblebeforecollapse", function(event) {
      $(this).find(".ui-collapsible-content").each(function() {
        $(this).stop().slideUp("fast");
      });
      return true;
    })
    .find(".ui-collapsible-content").css({
      "display": "block"
    });
});
```

```css
/* JQM no frills */
.ui-btn,
.ui-btn:hover,
.ui-btn:focus,
.ui-btn:active,
.ui-btn:visited {
  text-shadow: none !important;
}

/* Remove JQM blue halo */
.ui-btn:focus {
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

/* Speed-up some android & iOS devices */
* {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="My App">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
  <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0001, maximum-scale=1.0001, width=device-width, minimal-ui shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
      /* SEO - Remove h1 tag from loader */
      $.mobile.loader.prototype.defaultHtml = "<div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon-loading'></span><h6></h6></div>";

      /* Add onbefore events to the JQM collapsible */
      $.widget("mobile.collapsible", $.mobile.collapsible, {
        _handleExpandCollapse: function(isCollapse) {
          if(this._trigger("before" + (isCollapse ? "collapse" : "expand"))) {
            this._superApply(arguments);
          }
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="Gauntlet" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" class="ui-flipswitch-active ui-overlay-shadow">
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" role="main">
      <div data-role="collapsible-set">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-mini="true">
          <h3>Gauntlet Traits:</h3>

          <div class="ui-grid-b ui-responsive">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
              <select name="myList1" id="myList1" data-native-menu="false" data-mini="true">
                <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
                <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
                <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
                <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">
              <select name="myList2" id="myList2" data-native-menu="false" data-mini="true">
                <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
                <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
                <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
                <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-block-c">
              <select name="myList3" id="myList3" data-native-menu="false" data-mini="true">
                <option value="1">The 1st Option</option>
                <option value="2">The 2nd Option</option>
                <option value="3">The 3rd Option</option>
                <option value="4">The 4th Option</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-grid-solo">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
              <button type="button" id="submit" data-mini="true">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="table_div"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, it's not *exactly* an answer to the problem at hand, but it does fix the issue... I can use a navbar to hold my select menus, [a la this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040993/jquery-mobile-full-width-of-selects-fieldgroup).

Comment: Even if this answer shows research and effort from You and using a unordered list is somewhat more elegant than using nested `div`s, I strongly believe that it cannot be applied here because it refers to a way too old JQM version and also `navbar`s are useful in a completely different context (page navigation).

Comment: Yeah, I think your grids are probably the right way to go.. I had some difficulty implementing them, but I'll try again

Comment: I added a full working example, feel free to ask again if You have some trouble.