# A Google Apps Script mobile web app with configured HTML viewport is not displayed correctly

Tags: html, google-apps-script, mobile, web-applications

I would like to build a web app with Google Apps Script that is mainly used in its mobile version, so with a smaller screen. I'm using Bootstrap 5 for the layouting/grid system. The components should span the width of the mobile device screen, so `col-12` in Bootstraps grid system.

My simple Google Apps Script file to return the HTML is this:

```js
function doGet(e) {
    return HtmlService
        .createHtmlOutputFromFile('my-form')
        .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
}
```

So, I'm using `addMetaTag` to configure the viewport as suggested here: [Apps Script Web App elements are too small when viewed on a phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570083/apps-script-web-app-elements-are-too-small-when-viewed-on-a-phone)

This is the HTML file (`my-form.html`) for my web app:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Med-Form</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 offset-lg-2" style="background-color: lightgrey;">
                <header>A header</header>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mt-3">
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-8 offset-lg-2">

                <form>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                        <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a rather simple web form (actually the form is just an example code from Bootstraps docs).

The HTML file itself looks like this (correctly) with the Chome dev tools and a smaller screen device:

[image]

But, deployed as a Google Apps Script web app, again with the Chrome dev tools, the layout is not the same:

[image]

Google inserts a warning banner at the top of the web app. If I manually delete that row (it sits within a row of a table) as seen in the screenshot below, the layout matches the HTML file with its mobile layout (the first screenshot above).

[image]

So, it seems that the warning banner is the reason the mobile version of the web app is not displayed correctly. But to my knowledge, there is now way to hide that warning banner.

What must I do, so my web app is displayed correctly on smaller screen devices?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You could try adding negative left margin to the body in the iframe.

Comment: @TheMaster If I just move the content to the left, the desktop layout stays, it is not the mobile layout. Furthermore, the text input fields are too wide, causing the viewport to be scrollable horizontally. I'm a bit baffled why it is so hard to achieve a sufficient GAS mobile Web App.

Comment: It looks like a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/298287665) has already been created for this. Last update from Google is that a "a fix is in progress and will be rolling out with the next release"  though there's no ETA on when that next release will be made public.

Comment: @DuuEyn Consider adding the comment as a answer (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72731909)). Also the issue is `P1`, which rarely happens - so, a fix might be coming sooner than later.

Comment: @DuuEyn Thank you for providing the link. I’m glad it is handled as a bug officially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Issue was marked FIXED.

---

This is a known issue. As [mentioned by DuuEyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77079491/a-google-apps-script-mobile-web-app-with-configured-html-viewport-is-not-display?noredirect=1#comment135891647_77079491), It was reported here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/298287665

You can add a +1 to the bug report for a chance to increase it's priority.

Comment: The issue has been marked as fixed, with this comment: „I am marking this issue as FIXED as the internally reported issue has been marked as FIXED. Please note that there may be a delay in rolling this out to production. Thank you for your patience and please comment here if the issue remains.“

Comment: @It'sLeto As this is a community post, feel free to [edit] to put the latest status inside the answer directly.