# Problem with clickable image on touchscreens (phones)

Tags: html, google-apps-script, mobile, touchscreen, clickable-image

I created this clickable map, that opens questions according to where you click. But only some areas are clickable when it's on the phone, and as well the X button is huge on the phone when clicked on first area, but later areas the X button is normal size. I am really lost on how to fix these issues... I need to publish this survey by tomorrow, and i am so lost.

```js
function remove(el) {
  var element = el;
  element.remove();
}

function closeArea(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById('question-item-' + id);
  element.remove();
}
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("area"), function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var id = el.getAttribute("data-target").replace("questions", "");
    var content = document.getElementById("hidden-question").innerHTML.replaceAll("{NMB}", id);
    $("#questions-to-show").prepend(content);
  });
});
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("area"), function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e) {
    var id = el.getAttribute("data-target").replace("questions", "");
    var content = document.getElementById("hidden-question").innerHTML.replaceAll("{NMB}", id);
    $("#questions-to-show").prepend(content);
  });
});

function submitAnswer1answer1() {
  $('#form').validate();
  if (!$('#form').valid()) {
    alert("Please fill all fields!")
    return;
  }
  var form_data = document.getElementById("cotnent-body").getElementsByTagName("input");

  var i;
  var data = [];
  for (i = 0; i < form_data.length; i++) {
    if (form_data[i].checked || form_data[i].type == "text")
      data.push(form_data[i].value);
  }
  //console.log(data)
  google.script.run.saveData(data); // send to google app script
  document.getElementById("content-hide").style.display = "none"; // make form invisible
  document.getElementById("fomr-finished").style.display = "block"; // Optional if you want to give a completion feedback!
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Add the "required" attribute to all input elements
  $('input').attr('required', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<h1>
  Pain Characteristics
</h1>
<p><b>Click on the areas you experiance <b><u>chronic pain</u></b>, then scroll down and answer the questions.</b><br> No limit to how many areas you can choose.<br>(Chronic pain - longer than 3 months)</p>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/SKGt6C8/Body.jpg" usemap="#image-map" id="clickable-image" />
<map name="image-map">
        <area title="1" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 1" data-target="questions1" coords="159,165,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="2" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 2" data-target="questions2" coords="208,164,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="3" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 3" data-target="question3" coords="117,193,12" shape="circle">
        <area title="4" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 4" data-target="questions4" coords="248,193,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 6" data-target="questions6" title="6" coords="256,291,NaN"
          shape="circle">
        <area style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 5" data-target="questions5" title="5" coords="110,289,NaN"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="7" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 7" data-target="questions7" coords="157,217,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="8" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 8" data-target="questions8" coords="209,214,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="9" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 9" data-target="questions9" coords="160,262,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="10" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 10" data-target="questions10" coords="209,262,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="11" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 11" data-target="questions11" coords="153,307,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="12" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 12" data-target="questions12" coords="212,309,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="13" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 13" data-target="questions13" coords="143,354,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="14a" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 14a" data-target="questions14a" coords="181,333,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="14b" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 14b" data-target="questions14b" coords="182,368,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="15" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 15" data-target="questions15" coords="223,354,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="16" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 16" data-target="questions16" coords="150,427,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="17" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 17" data-target="questions17" coords="220,429,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="18" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 18" data-target="questions18" coords="153,530,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="19" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 19" data-target="questions19" coords="213,530,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="20" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 20" data-target="questions20" coords="153,621,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="21" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 21" data-target="questions21" coords="210,621,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="22" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 22" data-target="questions22" coords="430,163,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="23" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 23" data-target="questions23" coords="478,164,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="24" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 24" data-target="questions24" coords="388,191,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="25" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 25" data-target="questions25" coords="519,192,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="26" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 26" data-target="questions26" coords="381,290,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="27" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 27" data-target="questions27" coords="527,287,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="28" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 28" data-target="questions28" coords="427,213,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="29" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 29" data-target="questions29" coords="479,213,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="30" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 30" data-target="questions30" coords="429,259,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="31" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 31" data-target="questions31" coords="479,259,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="32" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 32" data-target="questions32" coords="425,306,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="33" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 33" data-target="questions33" coords="483,306,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="34" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 34" data-target="questions34" coords="413,352,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="35a" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 35a" data-target="questions35a" coords="454,332,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="35b" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 35b" data-target="questions35b" coords="455,369,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="36" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 36" data-target="questions36" coords="493,352,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="37" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 37" data-target="questions37" coords="418,427,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="38" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 38" data-target="questions38" coords="485,426,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="39" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 39" data-target="questions39" coords="423,528,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="40" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 40" data-target="questions40" coords="484,528,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="41" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 41" data-target="questions41" coords="426,619,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="42" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 42" data-target="questions42" coords="485,620,12"
          shape="circle">
      </map>


<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 50px; display: none;" id="fomr-finished">
  <h1>Thanks for completing the form!</h1>
  <p>We appreciate your time and information.</p>
</div>
</body>

<div id="hidden-question" style="display: none;">
  <div id="question-item-{NMB}" class="questions">
    <form>
      <div class="nav-cancel is-active" style="position: absolute;">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" style="cursor:pointer;" viewBox="0 0 24 24" onclick="closeArea('{NMB}')">
            <path
              d="M24 20.188l-8.315-8.209 8.2-8.282-3.697-3.697-8.212 8.318-8.31-8.203-3.666 3.666 8.321 8.24-8.206 8.313 3.666 3.666 8.237-8.318 8.285 8.203z" />
          </svg>
      </div>
      <h2>Area {NMB}</h2>
      <style>
        h2 {
          font-size: 36px;
        }
      </style>
      <div class="Qr7Oae" role="listitem">
        <input type="text" value="Area {NMB}" style="display: none;">
        <div jsmodel="CP1oW" data-params="%.@.[1631360647,&quot;On average, how intense is the chronic pain&quot;,null,5,[[142468032,[[&quot;0&quot;],[&quot;1&quot;],[&quot;2&quot;],[&quot;3&quot;],[&quot;4&quot;],[&quot;5&quot;],[&quot;6&quot;],[&quot;7&quot;],[&quot;8&quot;],[&quot;9&quot;],[&quot;10&quot;]],true,[&quot;No pain&quot;,&quot;Severe pain&quot;],[],null,null,null,null,null,[null,[]]]],null,null,null,[],null,null,[null,&quot;On average, how <u>intense</u> is the pre-menstrual pain (pain before periods)?&quot;]],&quot;i23&quot;,&quot;i24{NMB}&quot;,&quot;i25{NMB}&quot;,false]">
          <div class="M4DNQ">
            <div id="q1a1{NMB}" class="HoXoMd D1wxyf RjsPE" role="heading" aria-level="3" aria-describedby="i26{NMB}">
              <span class="M7eMe">On average, how <b><u>intense</u></b> is the chronic pain&nbsp;</span>
              <span class="vnumgf" id="q1a1{NMB}" aria-label="Required question"> *</span>
            </div>
            <div class="gubaDc OIC90c RjsPE" id="i24{NMB}"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="lLfZXe fnxRtf BpKDyb" jscontroller="wPRNsd" jsshadow="" jsaction="keydown: I481le;JIbuQc:JIbuQc;rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b" jsname="cnAzRb" aria-labelledby="q1a1{NMB}" aria-describedby="i24{NMB} i25{NMB}" aria-required="true" role="radiogroup">
            <br>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="0" required>
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">0 (No pain)</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="1">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">1</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="2">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">2</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="3">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">3</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="4">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">4</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="5">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">5</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="6">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">6</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="7">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">7</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="8">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">8</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="9">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">9</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="10">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">10 (Severe pain)</span>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div jsname="Rfh2Tc" class="SL4Sz" id="q1a1{NMB}" role="alert"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Area {NMB}"></div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="Qr7Oae" role="listitem">
        <div jsmodel="CP1oW" data-params="%.@.[1631360647,&quot;On average, what is the duration of the chronic pain?&quot;,null,5,[[142468032,[[&quot;0&quot;],[&quot;1&quot;],[&quot;2&quot;],[&quot;3&quot;],[&quot;4&quot;],[&quot;5&quot;],[&quot;6&quot;],[&quot;7&quot;],[&quot;8&quot;],[&quot;9&quot;],[&quot;10&quot;]],true,[&quot;No pain&quot;,&quot;Severe pain&quot;],[],null,null,null,null,null,[null,[]]]],null,null,null,[],null,null,[null,&quot;On average,what is the duration of the chronic pain?&quot;]],&quot;q1a1{NMB}&quot;,&quot;i24{NMB}&quot;,&quot;i25{NMB}&quot;,false]">
          <div class="M4DNQ">
            <div id="q1a1{NMB}" class="HoXoMd D1wxyf RjsPE" role="heading" aria-level="3" aria-describedby="i26{NMB}">
              <span class="M7eMe">On average, what is the <b><u>duration</u></b> of the
                  chronic pain &nbsp;</span>
              <span class="vnumgf" id="i26{NMB}" aria-label="Required question"> *</span>
            </div>
            <div class="gubaDc OIC90c RjsPE" id="i24{NMB}"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="lLfZXe fnxRtf BpKDyb" jscontroller="wPRNsd" jsshadow="" jsaction="keydown: I481le;JIbuQc:JIbuQc;rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b" jsname="cnAzRb" aria-labelledby="q1a1{NMB}" aria-describedby="i24{NMB} i25{NMB}" aria-required="true" role="radiogroup">
            <br>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="duration1{NMB}" value="1" required>
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">3-4 months</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="duration1{NMB}" value="2">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">5-6 months</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="duration1{NMB}" value="3">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">7-8 months</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="duration1{NMB}" value="4">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">9-10 months</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="duration1{NMB}" value="5">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">11-12 months</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="duration1{NMB}" value="6">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">More than a year</span>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div jsname="Rfh2Tc" class="SL4Sz" id="i25{NMB}" role="alert"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Area {NMB}"></div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="Qr7Oae" role="listitem">
        <div jsmodel="CP1oW" data-params="%.@.[1631360647,&quot;Do you take pain killers for the pain?&quot;,null,5,[[142468032,[[&quot;0&quot;],[&quot;1&quot;],[&quot;2&quot;],[&quot;3&quot;],[&quot;4&quot;],[&quot;5&quot;],[&quot;6&quot;],[&quot;7&quot;],[&quot;8&quot;],[&quot;9&quot;],[&quot;10&quot;]],true,[&quot;No pain&quot;,&quot;Severe pain&quot;],[],null,null,null,null,null,[null,[]]]],null,null,null,[],null,null,[null,&quot;Do you take pain killers for the pain&quot;]],&quot;q1a2&quot;,&quot;i24{NMB}&quot;,&quot;i25{NMB}&quot;,false]">
          <div class="M4DNQ">
            <div id="q2a1" class="HoXoMd D1wxyf RjsPE" role="heading" aria-level="3" aria-describedby="i26{NMB}">
              <span class="M7eMe">Do you take <b><u>pain killers</u></b> for the pain&nbsp;</span>
              <span class="vnumgf" id="i26{NMB}" aria-label="Required question"> *</span>
            </div>
            <div class="gubaDc OIC90c RjsPE" id="i24{NMB}"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="lLfZXe fnxRtf BpKDyb" jscontroller="wPRNsd" jsshadow="" jsaction="keydown: I481le;JIbuQc:JIbuQc;rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b" jsname="cnAzRb" aria-labelledby="q2a1" aria-describedby="i24{NMB} i25{NMB}" aria-required="true" role="radiogroup">
            <br>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="painkillers1{NMB}" value="1" required>
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">Yes</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="painkilles1{NMB}" value="2">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">No</span>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div jsname="Rfh2Tc" class="SL4Sz" id="i25{NMB}" role="alert"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Area {NMB}"></div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="Qr7Oae" role="listitem">
        <div jsmodel="CP1oW" data-params="%.@.[1631360647,&quot;If yes, do they help?&quot;,null,5,[[142468032,[[&quot;0&quot;],[&quot;1&quot;],[&quot;2&quot;],[&quot;3&quot;],[&quot;4&quot;],[&quot;5&quot;],[&quot;6&quot;],[&quot;7&quot;],[&quot;8&quot;],[&quot;9&quot;],[&quot;10&quot;]],true,[&quot;No pain&quot;,&quot;Severe pain&quot;],[],null,null,null,null,null,[null,[]]]],null,null,null,[],null,null,[null,&quot;If yes, do they help?&quot;]],&quot;q2a1&quot;,&quot;i24{NMB}&quot;,&quot;i25{NMB}&quot;,false]">
          <div class="M4DNQ">
            <div id="q3a1" class="HoXoMd D1wxyf RjsPE" role="heading" aria-level="3" aria-describedby="i26{NMB}">
              <span class="M7eMe"><b><u>If yes</u></b>, do they help?</span>
              <span class="vnumgf" id="i26{NMB}" aria-label="Required question"> *</span>
            </div>
            <div class="gubaDc OIC90c RjsPE" id="i24{NMB}"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="lLfZXe fnxRtf BpKDyb" jscontroller="wPRNsd" jsshadow="" jsaction="keydown: I481le;JIbuQc:JIbuQc;rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b" jsname="cnAzRb" aria-labelledby="q3a1" aria-describedby="i24{NMB} i25{NMB}" aria-required="true" role="radiogroup">
            <br>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="painkillers2{NMB}" value="0">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">Do not take painkillers</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="painkillers2{NMB}" value="1">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">They don't help</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="painkillers{NMB}" value="2">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">Help rarely</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity2{NMB}" value="3">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">Help sometimes</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity2{NMB}" value="4">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">Help most of the times</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity2{NMB}" value="5">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">Always help</span>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div jsname="Rfh2Tc" class="SL4Sz" id="i25{NMB}" role="alert"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Area {NMB}"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbynVUGIq2I-9-I5Iu7NLhR0MbWo7eYSzBLA4wK2tGcd4ZJPzvx-tZsTIPOXh0KZzpn1/exec
```

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbynVUGIq2I-9-I5Iu7NLhR0MbWo7eYSzBLA4wK2tGcd4ZJPzvx-tZsTIPOXh0KZzpn1/exec

Comment: Also spelling: `cotnent`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Regarding buttons being large, related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56602030

Answer (score 0):

You have jQuery. Use it

```
$("area").on("click touchstart", function() {
  const id = $(this).data("target").replace("questions", "");
  let content = $("#hidden-question").html();
  content = content.replaceAll("{NMB}", id);
  $("#questions-to-show").prepend(content).show(); 
});
// hide the question (you will need to .show() too - see above
$(document).on("click", ".close", () => { // delegation
  $("#questions-to-show").hide()
});
```

I removed the svg and added this. There is no need for a fixed size svg when you can just have a unicode character

```
<style>
  h2 {
    font-size: 36px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  h2 span.close {
    font-size: 46px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    margin-right: 14px
  }
</style>


<div id="hidden-question" style="display: none;">
  <div id="question-item-{NMB}" class="questions">
    <form>
      <h2>
        <span class="close">⨯</span>Area {NMB}
      </h2>
```

```js
$("area").on("click touchstart", function() {
  const id = $(this).data("target").replace("questions", "");
  let content = $("#hidden-question").html();
  content = content.replaceAll("{NMB}", id);
  $("#questions-to-show").prepend(content).show();
});
$(document).on("click", ".close", () => { // delegation
  $("#questions-to-show").hide()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<h1>
  Pain Characteristics
</h1>
<p><b>Click on the areas you experiance <b><u>chronic pain</u></b>, then scroll down and answer the questions.</b><br> No limit to how many areas you can choose.<br>(Chronic pain - longer than 3 months)</p>
<img src="https://i.ibb.co/SKGt6C8/Body.jpg" usemap="#image-map" id="clickable-image" />
<map name="image-map">
        <area title="1" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 1" data-target="questions1" coords="159,165,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="2" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 2" data-target="questions2" coords="208,164,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="3" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 3" data-target="question3" coords="117,193,12" shape="circle">
        <area title="4" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 4" data-target="questions4" coords="248,193,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 6" data-target="questions6" title="6" coords="256,291,NaN"
          shape="circle">
        <area style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 5" data-target="questions5" title="5" coords="110,289,NaN"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="7" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 7" data-target="questions7" coords="157,217,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="8" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 8" data-target="questions8" coords="209,214,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="9" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 9" data-target="questions9" coords="160,262,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="10" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 10" data-target="questions10" coords="209,262,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="11" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 11" data-target="questions11" coords="153,307,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="12" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 12" data-target="questions12" coords="212,309,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="13" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 13" data-target="questions13" coords="143,354,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="14a" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 14a" data-target="questions14a" coords="181,333,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="14b" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 14b" data-target="questions14b" coords="182,368,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="15" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 15" data-target="questions15" coords="223,354,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="16" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 16" data-target="questions16" coords="150,427,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="17" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 17" data-target="questions17" coords="220,429,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="18" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 18" data-target="questions18" coords="153,530,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="19" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 19" data-target="questions19" coords="213,530,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="20" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 20" data-target="questions20" coords="153,621,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="21" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 21" data-target="questions21" coords="210,621,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="22" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 22" data-target="questions22" coords="430,163,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="23" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 23" data-target="questions23" coords="478,164,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="24" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 24" data-target="questions24" coords="388,191,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="25" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 25" data-target="questions25" coords="519,192,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="26" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 26" data-target="questions26" coords="381,290,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="27" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 27" data-target="questions27" coords="527,287,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="28" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 28" data-target="questions28" coords="427,213,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="29" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 29" data-target="questions29" coords="479,213,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="30" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 30" data-target="questions30" coords="429,259,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="31" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 31" data-target="questions31" coords="479,259,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="32" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 32" data-target="questions32" coords="425,306,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="33" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 33" data-target="questions33" coords="483,306,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="34" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 34" data-target="questions34" coords="413,352,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="35a" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 35a" data-target="questions35a" coords="454,332,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="35b" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 35b" data-target="questions35b" coords="455,369,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="36" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 36" data-target="questions36" coords="493,352,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="37" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 37" data-target="questions37" coords="418,427,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="38" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 38" data-target="questions38" coords="485,426,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="39" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 39" data-target="questions39" coords="423,528,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="40" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 40" data-target="questions40" coords="484,528,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="41" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 41" data-target="questions41" coords="426,619,12"
          shape="circle">
        <area title="42" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Area 42" data-target="questions42" coords="485,620,12"
          shape="circle">
      </map>
<div id="questions-to-show"></div>

<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 50px; display: none;" id="form-finished">
  <h1>Thanks for completing the form!</h1>
  <p>We appreciate your time and information.</p>
</div>

<style>
  h2 {
    font-size: 36px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  h2 span.close {
    font-size: 46px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    margin-right: 14px
  }
</style>


<div id="hidden-question" style="display: none;">
  <div id="question-item-{NMB}" class="questions">
    <form>
      <h2>
        <span class="close">⨯</span>Area {NMB}
      </h2>
      <div class="Qr7Oae" role="listitem">
        <input type="text" value="Area {NMB}" style="display: none;">
        <div jsmodel="CP1oW" data-params="%.@.[1631360647,&quot;On average, how intense is the chronic pain&quot;,null,5,[[142468032,[[&quot;0&quot;],[&quot;1&quot;],[&quot;2&quot;],[&quot;3&quot;],[&quot;4&quot;],[&quot;5&quot;],[&quot;6&quot;],[&quot;7&quot;],[&quot;8&quot;],[&quot;9&quot;],[&quot;10&quot;]],true,[&quot;No pain&quot;,&quot;Severe pain&quot;],[],null,null,null,null,null,[null,[]]]],null,null,null,[],null,null,[null,&quot;On average, how <u>intense</u> is the pre-menstrual pain (pain before periods)?&quot;]],&quot;i23&quot;,&quot;i24{NMB}&quot;,&quot;i25{NMB}&quot;,false]">
          <div class="M4DNQ">
            <div id="q1a1{NMB}" class="HoXoMd D1wxyf RjsPE" role="heading" aria-level="3" aria-describedby="i26{NMB}">
              <span class="M7eMe">On average, how <b><u>intense</u></b> is the chronic pain&nbsp;</span>
              <span class="vnumgf" id="q1a1{NMB}" aria-label="Required question"> *</span>
            </div>
            <div class="gubaDc OIC90c RjsPE" id="i24{NMB}"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="lLfZXe fnxRtf BpKDyb" jscontroller="wPRNsd" jsshadow="" jsaction="keydown: I481le;JIbuQc:JIbuQc;rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b" jsname="cnAzRb" aria-labelledby="q1a1{NMB}" aria-describedby="i24{NMB} i25{NMB}" aria-required="true" role="radiogroup">
            <br>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="0" required>
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">0 (No pain)</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="1">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">1</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="2">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">2</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="3">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">3</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="4">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">4</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="5">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">5</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="6">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">6</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="7">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">7</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="8">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">8</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="9">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">9</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity{NMB}" value="10">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">10 (Severe pain)</span>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div jsname="Rfh2Tc" class="SL4Sz" id="q1a1{NMB}" role="alert"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Area {NMB}"></div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="Qr7Oae" role="listitem">
        <div jsmodel="CP1oW" data-params="%.@.[1631360647,&quot;On average, what is the duration of the chronic pain?&quot;,null,5,[[142468032,[[&quot;0&quot;],[&quot;1&quot;],[&quot;2&quot;],[&quot;3&quot;],[&quot;4&quot;],[&quot;5&quot;],[&quot;6&quot;],[&quot;7&quot;],[&quot;8&quot;],[&quot;9&quot;],[&quot;10&quot;]],true,[&quot;No pain&quot;,&quot;Severe pain&quot;],[],null,null,null,null,null,[null,[]]]],null,null,null,[],null,null,[null,&quot;On average,what is the duration of the chronic pain?&quot;]],&quot;q1a1{NMB}&quot;,&quot;i24{NMB}&quot;,&quot;i25{NMB}&quot;,false]">
          <div class="M4DNQ">
            <div id="q1a1{NMB}" class="HoXoMd D1wxyf RjsPE" role="heading" aria-level="3" aria-describedby="i26{NMB}">
              <span class="M7eMe">On average, what is the <b><u>duration</u></b> of the
                  chronic pain &nbsp;</span>
              <span class="vnumgf" id="i26{NMB}" aria-label="Required question"> *</span>
            </div>
            <div class="gubaDc OIC90c RjsPE" id="i24{NMB}"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="lLfZXe fnxRtf BpKDyb" jscontroller="wPRNsd" jsshadow="" jsaction="keydown: I481le;JIbuQc:JIbuQc;rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b" jsname="cnAzRb" aria-labelledby="q1a1{NMB}" aria-describedby="i24{NMB} i25{NMB}" aria-required="true" role="radiogroup">
            <br>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="duration1{NMB}" value="1" required>
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">3-4 months</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="duration1{NMB}" value="2">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">5-6 months</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="duration1{NMB}" value="3">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">7-8 months</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="duration1{NMB}" value="4">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">9-10 months</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="duration1{NMB}" value="5">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">11-12 months</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="duration1{NMB}" value="6">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">More than a year</span>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div jsname="Rfh2Tc" class="SL4Sz" id="i25{NMB}" role="alert"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Area {NMB}"></div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="Qr7Oae" role="listitem">
        <div jsmodel="CP1oW" data-params="%.@.[1631360647,&quot;Do you take pain killers for the pain?&quot;,null,5,[[142468032,[[&quot;0&quot;],[&quot;1&quot;],[&quot;2&quot;],[&quot;3&quot;],[&quot;4&quot;],[&quot;5&quot;],[&quot;6&quot;],[&quot;7&quot;],[&quot;8&quot;],[&quot;9&quot;],[&quot;10&quot;]],true,[&quot;No pain&quot;,&quot;Severe pain&quot;],[],null,null,null,null,null,[null,[]]]],null,null,null,[],null,null,[null,&quot;Do you take pain killers for the pain&quot;]],&quot;q1a2&quot;,&quot;i24{NMB}&quot;,&quot;i25{NMB}&quot;,false]">
          <div class="M4DNQ">
            <div id="q2a1" class="HoXoMd D1wxyf RjsPE" role="heading" aria-level="3" aria-describedby="i26{NMB}">
              <span class="M7eMe">Do you take <b><u>pain killers</u></b> for the pain&nbsp;</span>
              <span class="vnumgf" id="i26{NMB}" aria-label="Required question"> *</span>
            </div>
            <div class="gubaDc OIC90c RjsPE" id="i24{NMB}"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="lLfZXe fnxRtf BpKDyb" jscontroller="wPRNsd" jsshadow="" jsaction="keydown: I481le;JIbuQc:JIbuQc;rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b" jsname="cnAzRb" aria-labelledby="q2a1" aria-describedby="i24{NMB} i25{NMB}" aria-required="true" role="radiogroup">
            <br>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="painkillers1{NMB}" value="1" required>
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">Yes</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="painkilles1{NMB}" value="2">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">No</span>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div jsname="Rfh2Tc" class="SL4Sz" id="i25{NMB}" role="alert"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Area {NMB}"></div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="Qr7Oae" role="listitem">
        <div jsmodel="CP1oW" data-params="%.@.[1631360647,&quot;If yes, do they help?&quot;,null,5,[[142468032,[[&quot;0&quot;],[&quot;1&quot;],[&quot;2&quot;],[&quot;3&quot;],[&quot;4&quot;],[&quot;5&quot;],[&quot;6&quot;],[&quot;7&quot;],[&quot;8&quot;],[&quot;9&quot;],[&quot;10&quot;]],true,[&quot;No pain&quot;,&quot;Severe pain&quot;],[],null,null,null,null,null,[null,[]]]],null,null,null,[],null,null,[null,&quot;If yes, do they help?&quot;]],&quot;q2a1&quot;,&quot;i24{NMB}&quot;,&quot;i25{NMB}&quot;,false]">
          <div class="M4DNQ">
            <div id="q3a1" class="HoXoMd D1wxyf RjsPE" role="heading" aria-level="3" aria-describedby="i26{NMB}">
              <span class="M7eMe"><b><u>If yes</u></b>, do they help?</span>
              <span class="vnumgf" id="i26{NMB}" aria-label="Required question"> *</span>
            </div>
            <div class="gubaDc OIC90c RjsPE" id="i24{NMB}"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="lLfZXe fnxRtf BpKDyb" jscontroller="wPRNsd" jsshadow="" jsaction="keydown: I481le;JIbuQc:JIbuQc;rcuQ6b:rcuQ6b" jsname="cnAzRb" aria-labelledby="q3a1" aria-describedby="i24{NMB} i25{NMB}" aria-required="true" role="radiogroup">
            <br>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="painkillers2{NMB}" value="0">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">Do not take painkillers</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="painkillers2{NMB}" value="1">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">They don't help</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="painkillers{NMB}" value="2">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">Help rarely</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity2{NMB}" value="3">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">Help sometimes</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity2{NMB}" value="4">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">Help most of the times</span>
              </label>
            <label class="T5pZmf">
                <input type="radio" name="intensity2{NMB}" value="5">
                <span class="Zki2Ve" dir="auto">Always help</span>
              </label>
          </div>
          <div jsname="Rfh2Tc" class="SL4Sz" id="i25{NMB}" role="alert"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="Area {NMB}"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry no. That is a separate CSS issue. Perhaps ask a question with just the button and the css that makes it huge - use the `[<>]` stack snippet to show a [mcve]

Comment: It's somehow still not working on the phone :(
It worked the first time, but when I tried to open it again, it worked only on some areas of the picture.

Comment: The script I have posted (I had to add the `<div id="questions-to-show"></div>`) works fine on my iPhone and indeed the X is very large, I will have a look at that.

Comment: I have updaed the code to handle the X

Comment: I have realized the issue is that the radius of the coords areas was not big enough, it worked fine on the computer, but on phone, it was too small to get clicked I guess...i hope it continues to work! Thank you! I will try to figure out the button now.

Comment: Worked fin on my iPhone